# QGIS Distance Matrix execution fails

Tags: qgis, distance-matrix

I am trying to use the distance matrix to measure the distance between a crime (input ID) to the closest subway entrance (target layer). The problem is that sometimes the matrix comes out with results, sometimes it doesn't and instead, the algorithm fails.

I get this error in the distance matrix log

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\PointDistance.py", line 123, in processAlgorithm matType, nPoints, feedback) File
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\PointDistance.py", line 155, in linearMatrix fields, out_wkb, source.sourceCrs())
>   Exception: unknown
>
> Execution failed after 1.39 seconds
>
> Loading resulting layers Algorithm 'Distance matrix' finished

Comment: Do your layers have the same crs?

Comment: Yes, both layers are set to NAD83 and they both show up on the map

Comment: Got a similar issue `Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\PointDistance.py", line 135, in processAlgorithm
matType, nPoints, feedback)
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\PointDistance.py", line 177, in linearMatrix
index = QgsSpatialIndex(target_source.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setSubsetOfAttributes([]).setDestinationCrs(source.sourceCrs(), context.transformContext())), feedback)
Exception: unknown

Execution failed after 5.16 seconds`

Answer (score 1):

The error code is not helpful for this alg.

A way that works for me is to ensure that both layer are in the exact same CRS (preferably projected) and to ensure that the output layer is not used by any process.

Trying to replace a layer that is already in use will cause this error, in that case simply remove it from the projet and it should work.